# Help with SQL Join on two tables

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one is a table of forum threads. It has a last post date column.

Another table has PostID, UserId, and DateViewed.

I want to join these tables so I can compare DateViewed and LastPostDate for the current user. However, if they have never viewed the thread, there will not be a row in the 2nd table.

This seems easy but I cant wrap my head around it. Advice please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: trying left join. been using left outer

Comment: The `OUTER` is redundant.  It's the exact same thing as a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it that you're trying to do specifically - determine if there are unread posts?

You just need to use an outer join:

```
SELECT p.PostID, p.LastPostDate, ...,
    CASE
        WHEN v.DateViewed IS NULL OR v.DateViewed < p.LastPostDate THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS Unread
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN PostViews v
    ON v.PostID = p.PostID
    AND v.UserID = @UserID
```

Note that I've placed the `UserID` test in the `JOIN` condition; if you put it in the `WHERE` predicate then you'll get no results because there will be no matching rows in the `PostViews` table.

Comment: Ok, good... I was rereading your question and getting confused because I couldn't find any connection between threads and posts, but I guess you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

So you're thinking something like:

```
SELECT t.UserID, t.PostID, t.LastPostDate, v.DateViewed
FROM dbo.Threads t
LEFT JOIN dbo.Views v ON v.PostID = t.PostID
                     AND v.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE t.UserID = @user;
```

v.DateViewed will be NULL if there's no corresponding row in Views.

If you have lots of rows in Views, you may prefer to do something like:

```
SELECT t.UserID, t.PostID, t.LastPostDate, v.DateViewed
FROM dbo.Threads t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(vw.DateViewed) as DateViewed 
             FROM dbo.Views vw
             WHERE vw.PostID = t.PostID
               AND vw.UserID = t.UserID
            ) v
WHERE t.UserID = @user;
```

Comment: table t doesnt not have userid. UserId is only in the table holding the last time the viewed the thread.

That will be applied in the where at the time of execution

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will cause non-existent rows on the right side to come up as all `NULL`:

```
SELECT threads.lastpostdate, posts.dateviewed
FROM threads
LEFT JOIN posts
  ON threads.id=posts.postid
```